# Is this series divergent?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, convergence

I have $$G_N = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \left\{ \frac{1-\pi_i}{\pi_i} + \frac{1-\pi_i}{T\pi^2_i}\right\} (y_i-\theta)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{N} V_i$$ 
where $2\le T\le 10$, $0\le \pi_i\le1$ and suppose $y_i\sim N(\theta,1)$. I want to know whether $\sum_{i=1}^{N} V_i \rightarrow \infty$ as $N\rightarrow \infty$?

Any comment/answer will be much appropriated.

Comment: Why not cancel the common $\pi_i$ term in the second fraction?

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b. Cancelled in edited version.

Comment: If I'm looking at it correctly, at a first glance it seems to me that $G_N \to k \operatorname{Var}(Y) N$ for some constant $k > 0$ that depends on $\pi_i \in (0; 1)$ and $T$. $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = 1$. So, $G_N \to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks @Ertxiem. I think $G_N$ is divergent for any $Var(Y)$ because $Var(Y)=O(1)$.

Comment: How does $\pi_i$ vary with $i$?  Obviously if it goes to $1$ quickly enough the series converges...

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified sufficient information to determine the limit of the sum.  However, taking out the common factor in your bracketed term gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
V_i 
= \frac{1-\pi_i}{\pi_i} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{T\pi_i} \right) (y_i-\theta)^2 
&\sim \frac{1-\pi_i}{\pi_i} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{T\pi_i} \right) \chi_1^2. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

For brevity, I will refer to the limit $G_\infty = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} G_N$.  By choosing appropriate constants $T$ and $\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3, ...$, the limiting sum $G_\infty$ can be any arbitrary non-negative linear combination of chi-squared random variables, each with one degree-of-freedom.